# Red X in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

What exactly does a red 'X' in Active Directory represent? I know that a red 'X' over a user account means the account is disabled, but what does it represent when placed next to a Computer object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the computer object is disabled.  That would mean if the computer was switched on it would be denied access to the Domain.

> Every computer running Windows NT,
>   Windows 2000, Windows XP, or a server
>   running Windows Server 2003 that joins
>   a domain has a computer account.
>   Similar to user accounts, computer
>   accounts provide a means for
>   authenticating and auditing computer
>   access to the network and to domain
>   resources. Each computer account must
>   be unique.

Comment: Is there a way to enable the computer account? I mean, short of going to the actual computer and removing/re-adding back to the domain?

Comment: You should be able to right-click and select "Enable Account"

Comment: Odds are good, though, that it's disabled because it has been disjoined from the domain.